# Assigning value to a variable that has a "dot" in the name

Tags: r

I am new to R and was trying out the following code. To my surprise, assigning something to `ret$log.id` would actually caused to same value to be assigned to `ret$log` as well. E.g.,

```
 ret <- c()
 ret$log.id <- 'a'
```

Running the following would return `"a"`

```
ret$log
```

Is this what R supposed to do? I am hoping someone can give me some insight into this.

Thanks,

Comment: This is strange. If you run `str(ret)` or `names(ret)` the results are as I'd expect...a list of one with the name of "log.id". Interestingly, `ret$l` also returns "a" but `ret$z` returns NULL. I wonder if the `$` operator does some sort of best guess matching?

Comment: partial matching, it's not assigning to ret$log - use names(ret) to see what is really there (partial matching is one of R's boners)

Comment: Also see `options(warnPartialMatchDollar=T)` if you want to track these.

Comment: @Charles Please don't use `T` instead of `TRUE`.

Comment: I prefer to use TRUE in my code as well because it is easier to read. But is there any real difference between T and TRUE?

Comment: @ derek - it leads to ambiguity. For example, try `T <- FALSE`

Comment: @Derek More clearly: `T` could be overwritten (imagine that someone create `T`raining set), TRUE don't. And if you overwrite `T` error message will be far, far away from the real cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is normal behavior:

```
x = data.frame(happy = rnorm(10), sad = rnorm(10))

> x$hap
 [1] -0.9373243 -0.9497992 -0.1413024 -0.9857493  1.7156495  0.8715162  0.8377111
 [8] -0.4161816 -0.3976979 -0.2569765
```

I think Chase is right - partial matching in play.

Interestingly, if there are two columns that match the partial match, then NULL is returned instead of a warning:

```
y = data.frame(happy = rnorm(10), sad = rnorm(10), sadder = rnorm(10))

> y$sa
NULL
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the $ operator is doing some partial matching. You can explore the behavior a little with the following:

```
ret <- c()
ret$log.id <- "a"

ret$l #Returns "a"

ret$log.at <- "b"
```

Now see what's returned with the following:

```
ret$l
ret$log
ret$log.i
ret$log.a
```

Answer (score 6):

To elaborate on the partial matching boner. From the help page for `$`:

Under Arguments:

```
name     A literal character string or a name (possibly backtick quoted).
For extraction, this is normally (see under ‘Environments’) partially matched to the names 
of the object.
```

and then under Character indices:

```
Character indices can in some circumstances be partially matched (see pmatch) to the 
names or dimnames of the object being subsetted (but never for subassignment).
```

Also under Character indices:

```
Thus the default behaviour is to use partial matching only when extracting from 
recursive objects (except environments) by $. Even in that case, warnings can be 
switched on by options(warnPartialMatchAttr = TRUE).
```

There are more details as referenced in `names` and `pmatch` but that cleared it up for me.