# Strange behaviour dropping column from data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I've encountered a strange behavior when dropping columns from data.frame. Initially I have:

```
> a <- data.frame("a" = c(1,2,3), "abc" = c(3,2,1)); print(a)
  a abc
1 1   3
2 2   2
3 3   1
```

Now, I remove `a$a` from the data.frame

```
> a$a <- NULL; print(a)
  abc
1   3
2   2
3   1
```

As expected, I have only `abc` column in my data.frame. But the strange part begins, when I try to reference deleted column `a`.

```
> print(a$a)
[1] 3 2 1
> print(is.null(a$a))
[1] FALSE
```

It looks like R returns value of the `a$abc` instead of `NULL`.

This happens when the beginning of the name of remaining column exactly matches the name of deleted column.

Is it a bug or do I miss something here?

Comment: You are rigth @Chase, although the question's title is not the best to search for that.

Comment: @lselzer - I certainly concur there. I only knew it existed since I answered it. JD fixed this one and I'll go and update the other question accordingly. Or they should be merged...or something.

Comment: It's just R trying to be smart and guess what you mean. It figures that `a$a` means `a$abc` because that's the only possible option. This won't work for `a <- data.frame("a" = c(1,2,3), "b" = c(3,2,1)); a$a <- NULL ; is.null(a$a)`. It's just worked by chance in this case because both columns began with `a`.

Comment: As `help("$")` explains, `$` does partial matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your exact question has already been answered in the comments, an alternative to avoid this behaviour is to convert your `data.frame` to a `tibble`, which is a stripped downed version of a `data.frame`, without *column name munging*, among [other things](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/tibble.pdf):

```
library(tibble)
df_t <- as_data_frame(a)
df_t
# A tibble: 3 × 1
    abc
  <dbl>
1     3
2     2
3     1
> df_t$a
NULL
Warning message:
Unknown column 'a'
```

Comment: This is kind of a thing I'm looking for. Unfortunately, it's slower. According to my measurements (not extensive), 3 times slower.

Answer (score 8):

From the the help. ?$

> name: A literal character string or a
>   name (possibly backtick quoted). For
>   extraction, this is normally (see
>   under ‘Environments’) partially
>   matched to the names of the object.

So that's the normal behaviour because the name is partially matched. See ?pmatch for more info about partial matching.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it's worth pointing out (since it didn't come up on the previous [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065724/assigning-value-to-a-variable-that-has-a-dot-in-the-name)) that this partial matching behavior is potentially a reason to avoid using '$' except as a convenient shorthand when using R interactively (at least, it's a reason to be careful using it).

Selecting a column via `dat[,'ind']` if you know the name of the column, but not the position, or via `dat[,3]` if you know the position, is often safer since you won't run afoul of the partial matching.

Answer (score 0):

From the R Language Definition [section 3.4.1 pg.16-17] --

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.pdf

• **Character**:  The strings in i are matched against the names attribute of x and the resulting integers are used. For [[ and $ partial matching is used if exact matching fails, so x$aa will match x$aabb if x does not contain a component named "aa" and "aabb" is the only name which has prefix "aa". For [[, partial matching can be controlled via the exact argument which defaults to NA indicating that partial matching is allowed, but should result in a
warning when it occurs. Setting exact to TRUE prevents partial matching from occurring, a FALSE value allows it and does not issue any warnings. Note that [ always requires an exactmatch. The string "" is treated specially: it indicates ‘no name’ and matches no element (not even those without a name). Note that partial matching is only used when extracting
and not when replacing.